# mysql "create table if not exists", determine if table created

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to determine if a table was created or already existed when using `create table if not exists...`?

There seem to be two variables returned:

`(query ok, affected_rows)`

The query always returns (1, 0) regardless of if the table was created or already existed.

But it seems a `create schema if not exists` does return `affected_rows=1`.

Thanks.

Comment: you should specify what library or interface you are using to execute mysql queries to get better help

Comment: @ysth it is more about the MySQL protocol, and how it is inconsistent with `affected_rows` when creating schema vs creating tables.

Answer (score 3):

I get 1 warning if the table exists (mysql 8.0.25):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (`id` INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (`id` INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

The warning is `1050 Table 'test' already exists`

But you can just check if the table exists before creating it